# VBA worksheets loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have 24 sheets named 0 to 23 and need to loop command below for each sheet.
I have try some looping procedure as i found in many tutorials but none is work, need your suggestion here

```
Sheets("0").Select
Cells.Select
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

---

Recently I try this code but it stop on "Sheets(i).Select"
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

```
Dim i as integer
  For i = 0 To 23
   Sheets(i).Select
   Cells.Select
   Range("B1").Select
   Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
   Selection.Clear
 Next i
```

Comment: What range do you want to clear? There are three 'Range.Select' in your code, but only the range selected by "Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select" may be processed by 'Selection.ClearContents'.  I cannot understand what do you want from your code.  When your aim becomes clear, you may be able to receive good answer.

Comment: I need to clear all contents except in column A.

Comment: I need to clear all contents except in column A. And as additional info, each sheet has randomly amount in content. Actually I'm not really good in code, so I just record my macro manually then edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly you are asking how to loop through the worksheets in a workbook and execute the code you are showing, correct?  If so, see this Microsoft Support article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142126

Answer (score 0):

Reading the other answers and the related comments it is my understanding that you want to loop over all worksheets in the workbook and clear contents from anything but column A. You could do that like this:

```
        Sub AllButA()

        Dim ws As Worksheet


        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets '<~~ it will loop over the worksheets in the workbook
            For i = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 2 Step -1 '<~~ we go from the last used column in the sheet to column 2 (column B) from high to low to avoid messing with the indexes
                ws.Columns(i).ClearContents '<~~ we clear the column content
            Next
        Next


        End Sub
```

if you want to stick to the explicitly named worksheets you could do it like this:

```
        Sub AllButA()

        Dim ws As Worksheet


        For i = 0 To 23
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(i)) '<~~ instead of looping we assign the worksheet variable by name
            For j = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 2 Step -1 '<~~ same as the other example, just with j instead of i
                ws.Columns(j).ClearContents
            Next
        Next


        End Sub
```

If the latter fits your needs, please check the sheet names as Fumu 7 suggest

Answer (score -1):

VBA code to clear cells except column 'A' will be

```
Range("B1").Select  'select top left corner of range to be cleared.
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select  'select upto bottom right corner(xlLastCell) of range to be cleared.
Selection.Clear 'Clear selected cells.
```

To apply for worksheets named "0","1".....,"23", add loop for worksheets outside above code. That may become:

```
Dim i as integer, sheetname as string
Dim ws as Worksheet

For i=0 to 23
  sheetname=Cstr(i)   'create sheetname from number (loop variable i)
  set ws = worksheets(sheetname)    
  ws.Activate 'select worksheet with name  "0","1",... and "23" for each
  Range("B1").Select  'select top left corner of range to be cleared.
  Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select  'select upto bottom right corner(xlLastCell) of range to be cleared.
  Selection.Clear 'Clear selected cells.
next i
```

Comment: I've tried the code, but it stuck at "set ws = worksheets(sheetname) ". Subscript out of range. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please add "msgbox" to show the value of sheetname. Then check the worksheet with that name exist. "Subcription out of range" means "There is no worksheet which has that name". Sometime worksheet name as extra space characters, check carefully.